# s.replace() not working in Android EditText in TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an EditText in which the user should input a number including decimals and i want a thousand separator automatically added onto the input number
I tried a couple of other methods but some do not allow floating point numbers
so i came up with this code which works well only that the string input is not being edited in realtime to one with possible thousand separators and the errors seem to stem from the s.replace();

```
am2 = new TextWatcher(){
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.toString().equals("")) {
            amount.setText("");
            value = 0;
        }else{
            StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
            char c;
            for (int i = 0; i < amount2.getText().toString().length() ; i++) {
                c = amount2.getText().toString().charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    strBuff.append(c);
                }
            }
            value = Double.parseDouble(strBuff.toString());
            reverse();
            NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
            ((DecimalFormat)nf2).applyPattern("###,###.#######");
            s.replace(0, s.length(), nf2.format(value));
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `setText()` of the edittext once the text is changed
do something like this
`editext.setText(s);` after you replace your string

Comment: yes because...it will go on continous lopping as setting text in onTextChanged again call it....and agsin same which will causing looping...appling some locking mechanism....

Answer (score 0):

simple `s = s.replace(0, s.length(), nf2.format(value));`
That is variable  `s` need to be assigned.